# wp e-commerce - theme problem - why won't it load wpsc-single_product.php?

Tags: theme-development, e-commerce, plugin-wp-e-commerce

This is so frustrating!

The theme i made myself works fine with wp-e-commerce (getshopped) plugin, but for some reason it won't load wpsc-single_product.php when i view a single product.

When i change theme to twenty ten it works fine, so i'm positive that it has SOMETHING to do with my theme - But what? what do i eed to do in order to make my theme more compatible to wp-e-commerce?

My own theme is based on the bones responsive framework.

I'll appreciate any help, idea, clues - anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved! there was some other script related to google + that was causing the problem. I commented it out and worked around it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to flush the theme cache?  Found at Settings > Store > Presentation in the right column at the bottom.

Comment: Yes, i did, but that wasn't the problem.